# Finding new versus repeated users in sas

Tags: sas, proc-sql

Below given dataset I am trying to find New Users Vs Repeated Users.

```
DATE        ID       Unique_Event
20200901    a12345   1
20200902    a12345   1
20200903    b12345   1
20200903    a12345   1
20200904    c12345   1
```

In the above dataset, since a12345 appeared on multiple dates, should be counted as a "repeated" user whereas b12345 only appeared once, so he is a "new" user. Please note, this is only sample data as the actual data is quite large. I tried the below code, but I am not getting the correct count. Ideally, tot_num_users-num_new_users should be repeated users, but I am getting incorrect counts. Am I missing something?

```
Expected Output:
Month   new_users   repeated_users
9        2           1
```

Code:

```
data user_events;
set user_events;
new_date=input(date,yymmdd10.);
run;
proc sql;select  month(new_date) as mm,
       count(distinct vv.id) as total_num_users,
       count(distinct case when v.new_date = vv.minva then v.id end) as num_new_users,
   (count(distinct vv.id) - count(distinct case when v.new_date = vv.minva then id end)
   ) as num_repeated_users
from user_events v inner join
     (select t.id, min(new_date) as minva
      from user_events t
      group by t.id
     ) vv
     on v.id = vv.id
group by  1
order by 1;quit;
```

Comment: Could you please post a sample of the expected resulting dataset?

Comment: @LuizZ Added the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a sub-select, for each `ID` you can count the number of distinct `DATE` to determine the `new` / `repeated` status.  The all ids aggregate computations are made from the sub-select.

```
proc sql;
  create table freq as
  select 
    count(*) as id_count
  , sum (status='repeated') as id_repeated_count   /* sum counts a logic eval state */
  , sum (status='new')      as id_new_count
  from 
    ( select 
          id
        , case 
            when count(distinct date) > 1 then 'repeated' 
            else 'new'
          end as status
      from 
        user_events
      group by
        id
    ) as statuses
  ;
```

Comment: You are awesome

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution not using proc sql (though I'm aware you tagged this with "proc sql").

```
data final;
    set user_events;
    Month=month(new_date);
run;
proc sort data=final; by Month ID;

data final;
    set final;
    by Month ID;

    if first.Month then do;
        new_users=0;
        repeated_users=0;
    end;
    if last.ID then do;
        if first.ID then
            new_users+1;
        else
            repeated_users+1;
    end;
    if last.Month then
        output;

    keep Month new_users repeated_users;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using proc sql, this is a sql question, not a SAS question.
Try something like:

```
proc sql;
    select ID,count(Unique_Event)
    from <that table>
    group by ID
    order by ID
run;
```